# How do I use waf to build a shared library?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, waf

I want to build a shared library using [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) as it looks much easier and less cluttered than GNU autotools.

I actually have several questions so far related to the wscript I've started to write:

```
VERSION='0.0.1'
APPNAME='libmylib'

srcdir = '.'
blddir = 'build'

def set_options(opt):
 opt.tool_options('compiler_cc')
 pass

def configure(conf):
 conf.check_tool('compiler_cc')
 conf.env.append_value('CCFLAGS', '-std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic -ggdb')

def build(bld):
 bld.new_task_gen(
  features = 'cc cshlib',
  source = '*.c',
  target='libmylib')
```

The line containing `source = '*.c'` does not work. Must I specify each and every .c file instead of using a wildcard?

How can I enable a debug build for example (currently the wscript is using the debug builds CFLAGS, but I want to make this optional for the end user).

It is planned for the library sources to be within a sub directory, and programs that use the lib each in their own sub directories.

Comment: After asking this question I also asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596279/why-has-nobody-created-an-open-source-build-system-for-the-brain-dead
Which has lead me to investigate http://premake.sf.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest version of waf (1.5.9 at the time of writing), wild cards can be specified via the [`glob()`](http://freehackers.org/~tnagy/wafdoc/wafadmin.Build.BuildContext-class.html#glob) method on the build context. So you can write the following:

```
bld.new_task_gen(
    features = 'cc cshlib',
    source = bld.glob('*.c'),
    target='mylib')
```

If you were using an older version of waf that doesn't have glob, then there is a method `find_sources_in_dirs` that you can use:

```
lib = bld.new_task_gen(
    features = 'cc cshlib',
    target = 'mylib')
lib.find_sources_in_dirs('.')
```

This method is still in Waf but is slated for deprecation and may eventually disappear.

The `srcdir` and `blddir` variables are optional now so you don't need them - they default to "." and "build" anyway. You shouldn't prepend "lib" to the target name, this is done automatically in a platform specific way (on Windows no lib is added and shared libraries use .dll). Debug vs Release build is a surprisingly thorny issue. Originally Waf included this feature, but it was dropped at some point and never re-added. It's a common request on the mailing list so may resurface in the future. Meanwhile you could do a lot worse than use [gjc's cflags module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gjc/waf/cmd/annotate/head%3A/wafadmin/Tools/cflags.py). Just add it to your project directory. The final wscript would then be:

```
VERSION='0.0.1'
APPNAME='mylib'

def set_options(opt):
    opt.tool_options('compiler_cc')
    opt.tool_options('cflags', tooldir='.')

def configure(conf):
    conf.check_tool('compiler_cc')
    conf.check_tool('cflags', tooldir='.')

def build(bld):
    bld.new_task_gen(
        features = 'cc cshlib',
        source = bld.glob('*.c'),
        target=APPNAME)
```

And to set up a debug build you would run the following:

```
./waf configure -d debug
```

If you are using libraries in their own sub-directories, then you should probably have a top level wscript and use the [`bld.add_subdirs()`](http://freehackers.org/~tnagy/wafdoc/wafadmin.Build.BuildContext-class.html#add_subdirs) technique to add library/program directories. Each sub-directory would have its own wscript_build file. You can then use the [`export_incdirs`](http://freehackers.org/~tnagy/wafbook/ch08s02.html) and [`uselib_local`](http://freehackers.org/~tnagy/wafbook/ch08s02.html) properties to specify the correct include directories between library and program "modules".

Comment: Although I've not used it, another waf module that might be useful is autowaf.py: svn.drobilla.net/lad/trunk/autowaf.py
"Waf utilities for easily building standard unixey packages/libraries" it's GNU GPL v2 or later by Dave Robillard  and Nedko Arnaudov

Answer (score 3):

waf has changed a lot over the years so neither the code in the question nor the answer works with current waf anymore. Nowadays you just write:

```
def options(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_c')
def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_c')
def build(ctx):
    ctx.shlib(source = ctx.path.ant_glob('src/*.c'),
              target = 'name')
```

Note that waf will automatically add the `lib` prefix so you don't write `target 
 = 'libname'`. On Windows, you also have to add the `defs` keyword argument to the `shlib` function call.

Personally I would recommend against recursive build scripts involving `wscript_build` files. Not that it doesn't work (like [recursive makefiles](http://wiki.c2.com/?RecursiveMakeConsideredHarmful)), it's just much simpler to keep all logic in one medium-sized build script.